# AngularJS testing w/ jasmine and $httpBackend

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine

I'm experimenting with angular and I want to be able to run automated tests with jasmine. I'm having some trouble setting up the test environment. I have my controllers & services separated into separate files

app.js

```
(function (ng) {
'use strict';

ng.module('demo', ['marvel', 'ngRoute']);
}(window.angular));
```

controllers.js

```
(function (app) {
'use strict';

function paging(pageIndex, pageSize, total) {
    var url = '/characters/'
        , last = Math.floor(total / pageSize);

    this.first = pageIndex === 0 ? null : url + '0';
    this.previous = pageIndex === 0 ? null : url + (pageIndex - 1).toString();
    this.next = last <= pageIndex ? null : url + (pageIndex + 1);
    this.last = last <= pageIndex ? null : url + last;
};

app.controller('charactersController', function ($scope, $routeParams, marvelRepository) {
    var pageIndex = parseInt($routeParams.pageIndex);

    marvelRepository.fetch(pageIndex).then(function (data) {
        $scope.characters = data.results;
        $scope.paging = new paging(pageIndex, data.limit, data.total);
    });
});

app.controller('characterController', function ($scope, $window, $routeParams, marvelRepository) {
    var characterId = $routeParams.id;

    $scope.back = function () {
        $window.history.back();
    };

    marvelRepository.get(characterId).then(function (character) {
        $scope.character = character;
    });
});
}(window.angular.module('demo')));
```

marvel.js

```
(function (ng, crypto, date) {
'use strict';

var marvel = ng.module('marvel', ['ngResource']);

marvel.constant('marvelApiKey', {
    'public': '**public**'
    , 'private': '**private**'
});

marvel.provider('hash', function (marvelApiKey) {
    var _override = null;

    function Authentication () {
        this.authenticate = function () {
            var timeStamp = date.now().toString()
                , md5Hash = crypto.MD5(timeStamp + marvelApiKey.private + marvelApiKey.public).toString();

            return {
                apikey: marvelApiKey.public
                , ts: timeStamp
                , hash: md5Hash
            };
        };
    }

    this.override = function (authentication) {
        _override = function () {
            return authentication;
        };
    };

    this.$get = function () {
        return _override || new Authentication();
    }
});

marvel.service('marvelRepository', function (hash, $resource) {
    return {
        get: function (characterId) {
            var authentication = hash.authenticate();

            return $resource('http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/' + characterId, authentication)
                .get()
                .$promise
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.code !== 200) {
                        throw response;
                    }

                    return response.data.results[0];
                });
        },
        fetch: function (pageIndex) {
            var authentication = hash.authenticate();
            var args = ng.extend({limit:20, offset: pageIndex*20}, authentication);

            return $resource('http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters', args)
                .get()
                .$promise
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.code !== 200) {
                        throw response;
                    }

                    return response.data;
                });
        }
    };
});
}(window.angular, CryptoJS, Date));
```

What I would like to do is write an automated test that stubs out $httpBackend, but uses all the other components. I want to override the hashProvider values to fake my own for easier testing. here is what I have so far.

```
describe("Marvel Tests", function () {

beforeEach(function () {
    module('marvel', ['hashProvider', function (hashProvider) {
        hashProvider.override({
            apikey: '123'
                , ts: '20140601073322'
                , hash: 'abc123'
        });
    }]);

    module('demo');
});

it('should be able to get a page of characters', inject(function ($controller, $httpBackend) {
    var scope = {};

    $httpBackend.when('get', 'http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?apikey=123&ts=20140601073322&hash=abc123&limit=20&offset=20').respond(200, "{data: { results: new Array(20), offset: 2, limit 20, total: 100 } }");

    $controller('charactersController', {$scope: scope, $routeParams: { pageIndex: 1 }});

    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(scope.characters.length).equal(20);
    expect(scope.paging.total).equal(100);
}));
});
```

however I'm getting the following error

```
Marvel Tests should be able to get a page of characters.
TypeError: undefined is not a function
TypeError: undefined is not a function
  at Object.fetch (http://localhost:1236/js/marvel.js:55:43)
  at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:1236/js/controllers.js:25:26)
  at invoke (http://localhost:1236/js/angular/angular.js:4009:17)
  at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:1236/js/angular/angular.js:4020:23)
  at http://localhost:1236/js/angular/angular.js:7312:28
  at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:1236/tests/tests.js:30:9)
  at Object.invoke (http://localhost:1236/js/angular/angular.js:4009:17)
  at workFn (http://localhost:1236/tests/angular-mock.js:2181:30)
  at jasmine.Block.execute (http://localhost:1236/tests/jasmine.js:1064:17)
  at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://localhost:1236/tests/jasmine.js:2096:31)
Error: Declaration Location
  at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (http://localhost:1236/tests/angular-mock.js:2152:29)
  at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:1236/tests/tests.js:25:54)
  at jasmine.Env.describe (http://localhost:1236/tests/jasmine.js:819:21)
  at describe (http://localhost:1236/tests/jasmine.js:603:27)
  at http://localhost:1236/tests/tests.js:11:1
```

What am I missing to run an end-to-end test using $httpBackend?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you are registering your service under the name `marvelRepository`, but you are trying to inject a service named `$marvelRepository`.

Another error you will probably come accross is that you are trying to config the provider of a service named `hashProvider` like this:

```
.config(function (hashProvider) {...})
```

But, for configuring a service you need to inject its provider, which in the case of `hashProvider` wil be `hashProviderProvider`.

---

**UPDATE:**

The problem with your updated code is hard to determine without the ability to reproduce, but based on the stack-trace it seems like the angular might not have been properly initialized.

This might be due to how you call inject as the 2nd argument of the `it()` function, instead of something like this:

```
it('should be able to get a page of characters', function () {
    inject(function ($controller, $httpBackend) {
        var scope = {};
        ...
```

---

<sub>BTW, I am not really sure this syntax would work as exected:</sub>
<sub>`module('marvel', ['hashProvider', function (hashProvider) {...}])`</sub>
<sub>(just saying...)</sub>

Comment: that may have helped steer me in the right direction. Now I'm getting this error after renaming `hashProvider` to `hash` and altering the tests.

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer. It is hard to determine the issue though without being able to reproduce it.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean about the syntax looking a bit strange. Although this is what all the examples and tutorials show online.

Comment: @JasonMeckley: Did you try my updated solution ? Did it work ?

Comment: yes, I tried a couple variations, but no success. i'm wondering if I'm using the mocking library incorrectly. I want to load all the modules/directives, configure the app and then use $httpBackend to stub out the server calls.